# how to undo pictureBox drawline C# windows form using Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, drawing, undo, lifo

And trying get working small paint application, that draws only lines with mouse event.

Could someone provide me with correct working example how to create undo functionality?
I have picturebox1 with Events pictureBox1_MouseDown, pictureBox1_MouseMove, pictureBox1_MouseUp.

When I moving mouse and  and clicking on picture box it is drawing lines as expected.
But how to create undo functionality for example on undo button click?

```
     private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            lx = e.X;
            ly = e.Y;

            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(paintcolor), 3), new Point(x, y), new Point(lx, ly));


            this.Invalidate();

        }




   private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;

        }




  private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I create additionally

```
class Shape
{

    public string _font { get; set; }
    public string g { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int lx { get; set; }
    public int ly { get; set; }
    public string paintcolor { get; set; }
    public string s { get; set; }


}
```

then added   under **public partial class Form1 : Form**

```
private Stack<Shape> _shapes = new Stack<Shape>();
```

than add to **pictureBox1_MouseUp**

```
newShape._font = _font.ToString();
            newShape.g = g.ToString();
            newShape.x = x;
            newShape.y = y;
            newShape.lx = lx;
            newShape.ly = ly;
            newShape.paintcolor = paintcolor.ToString();




                _shapes.Push(newShape);


            this.Invalidate();
```

and for Undo button **btnUndo**

```
  private void btnUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (_shapes.Count > 0)
            {

                this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                _shapes.Pop();


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing to remove.", "No Shapes",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }

        }
```

and put break-point on  **_shapes.Push(newShape);**

that _shapes are filed with values

and when I push button **btnUndo**

I see that _shapes.Pop(); removing values LIFO, but of course my lines did not disappears.
So I'm confused because I have feeling that I need create lines on pictureBox1 not from mouse movements, but from Stack.

Comment: Shouldn't you Invalidate after you Pop the shape?

Comment: Yes, for **pictureBox1_MouseUp** </br>

_shapes.Push(newShape);

            //this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            //this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            this.Invalidate(); 

for **btnUndo_Click** tested </br>if (_shapes.Count > 0)
            {
                //   pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                _shapes.Pop();
                //this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();

            }

Comment: Winforms = winapi, so you have to follow its design. Move all drawing logic into `Paint` event, you already have some collection to hold figures to paint, in `Paint` event you just **repaint** all of them (with clearing background). To add figure: add it to collection, call `Invalidate` (this will execute `Paint` event, so you will see your figure). To delete: remove it from collection, call `Invalidate` (`Paint` will draw less figures - it will looks like it's *undone*).

Comment: Hi Sinatr, is behind your idea is something like this?   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dbeniwal321/adding-a-paint-event-handler-to-a-form-and-controls-in-gdi/

Comment: Thank You for advice, problem is solved.

Comment: Thank You for advice, problem is solved. I create on pictureBox1 one more event **Appearance -> Paint pictureBox1_Paint** and create and add in to   `   private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

                     
                foreach (Shape shp in _shapes)
                {
                 e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(paintcolor), 3), shp.x, shp.y, shp.lx, shp.ly);
         
                    
              
            }
        }` And then Pop() works as expected. Thanks for advice :)